# Makefile: prerequisite-only rule not firing

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Code:

```
DEST = <some-folder>
EXES = compiled1
SCRIPTS = script1
COPIED = $(addprefix $(DEST)/,$(EXES) $(SCRIPTS))

$(shell mkdir -p $(DEST))

all: $(COPIED)

$(EXES):
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

$(COPIED):
    cp $< $@
    chmod +x $@

$(DEST)/%: %
compiled1: compiled1.cpp
```

The idea is as follow: I have a folder with some scripts and source files. Source files are compiled to form 1 or more binary programs.

Then I need to copy both the scripts and the binary programs to a same destination folder. The scripts require, besides being copied, to be `chmod`ed. Compiled programs don't but I did it anyway to merge rules.

- The `all:` rule depends on the copied-files.

  - The `$(DEST)/%:` rule is meant to make sure each copied-file depends on my local version.

    - The `$(EXES):` rule generate the local binary programs.
    - The local scripts don't need to be generated, so there's no rule for them.

The problem is that, for some reason, the `$(DEST)/%: %` prerequisite-only rule is not firing, so within the `$(COPIED)` rule, `$<` is empty, and `cp` fails, and it should fire because `$(COPIED)` follows the `$(DEST)/%` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that, for some reason, the `$(DEST)/%: %` prerequisite-only rule is not firing, so within the `$(COPIED)` rule, `$<` is empty, and `cp` fails, and it should fire because `$(COPIED)` follows the `$(DEST)/%` pattern.

Prerequisite-only implicit rules do not make much sense for adding prerequisites to targets (and they specifically do not have that effect).  `make` will consider implicit rules for a given target only if there is no explicit rule for the target, and it will select *one* implicit rule from among those applicable for building it.  If no implicit rule matching a given target provides a recipe, and the target is not phony, then there must be an explicit rule that suffices to build it, and that moots all implicit rules for the same target.

**One alternative** would be to do the copying directly in the implicit rule, instead of having a separate rule for that:

```
# $(COPIED):
#     cp $< $@
#     chmod +x $@

$(DEST)/%: %
    cp $< $@
    chmod +x $@
```

All the files designated by `$(COPIED)` are named as prerequisites for `all`, so building `all` will trigger the implicit rule (with its recipe) for each of them.  You can also build any one of them explicitly, just as you could before.  You can *also* get `make` to try to build and copy other files, which is a potential weakness, but perhaps one you can live with.

**Another alternative** would be write a more conventional installation rule,<sup>*</sup> maybe something like this:

```
DEST = <some-folder>
EXES = compiled1
SCRIPTS = script1

all: $(EXES)

install: all
    mkdir -p -m 0755 $(DEST)
    cp $(EXES) $(SCRIPTS) $(DEST)
    chmod 0755 $(SCRIPTS)

.PHONY: all install
```

---

<sup>*</sup> And if the copying is not well characterized as installation, then maybe rethink more deeply.  If the copying does not require more privilege than the building does, then you probably shouldn't be doing it at all.  Instead, build the EXEs directly to the location where you want them, and distribute the scripts (or copies of them) pre-installed in that location (which must be within the distribution if you can be sure that no extra privilege is required to copy files there).

Comment: Ok I understand. I didn't know that implicit rule and pattern rule are synonyms. I did already what you described in your first solution, but didn't understand the reason why my original form didn't work until reading your post.

Comment: @AaronBueno, I'm glad that helped.  Yes, GNU `make` categorizes pattern rules as implicit rules, and its manual reflects that.  I've always found that a bit awkward, but that's the terminology GNU chose.

Comment: I guess the reason is that the built-in rules (which are truly implicit) are indeed pattern rules. They should have named implicit rule = built-in pattern rule instead.

Comment: Not all built-in rules are pattern rules.  The term "implicit rules" is used for any rule which operates implicitly on a group of targets which have a common trait, rather than operating on an explicitly named target (explicit rules).  In traditional make there is only one kind of implicit rule: a _suffix rule_.  GNU make supports suffix rules and it also supports pattern rules: both are implicit rules and that term is used to mean any rule that make uses to infer a recipe based on some part of the name of the target.

Comment: All bult-in rules are implicit (obviously since a bult-in rule can't list explicit targets that you might want to build) but not all built-in rules are pattern rules.  Some are suffix rules.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern rule prerequisites work differently than regular prerequisites -- they're not additive for one.  A pattern rule with no recipe will [cancel an implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html), so this does not do what you want.   To do what you're describing, you would likely want to do your copy right inside the pattern rule itself:

```
DEST = <some-folder>
EXES = compiled1
SCRIPTS = script1
COPIED = $(addprefix $(DEST)/,$(EXES) $(SCRIPTS))

all: $(COPIED)

$(EXES):
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

$(DEST):
    mkdir -p $@

$(DEST)/%: % | $(DEST)
    cp $< $@
    chmod +x $@

compiled1: compiled1.cpp
```